# Python Turtle Plot Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a plot regression function. The parameter for my function is a list of x,y coordinates which I have split into two lists (one x coordinate list and one y coordinate list). I have found the slope of the line and everything needed to plot the points but I need some help with writing a for loop to make my turtle draw the x,y points.
I have already drawn my axes and this is what I have so far when trying to plot the points.

```
for i,j in xPts,yPts:
    mad.up()
    mad.goto(i,j)
    mad.down()
    mad.dot()
```

For example I may have been given the list [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)] originally and I have split them apart so I have lists xPts=[1,3,5] and yPts=2,4,6].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you have already set up the screen with the correct dimensions to handle simple points like this, otherwise I would try multiplying the values by 100

```
for i in range(len(xPts)):
  mad.up()
  mad.goto(xPts[i], yPts[i])
  mad.down()
  mad.dot()
```

FYI you cannot iterate through to different lists in the same for statement and that is your problem